# Asking for a name. Ellipsis or not?

Tags: ellipses, dialogue

In dialogue, when a character is asking for another's name by saying, 'Mister...?' (expecting the other character to answer with their surname), is it written:

'Mister...?' or 'Mister?'

The first feels better, as it includes the implied gap, waiting to be filled by the answer.

Comment: I prefer *"Mister...?"* . It hints that the character speaking is expecting a response.

Answer (score 3):

The ellipsis indicates that the speaker's voice is trailing off. If that's your intended effect, then use it.  It is not required.

Answer (score 0):

To add to BiscuitBoy's and jimm101's responses, including the ellipsis is preferable as, since the reader cannot hear and comprehend written dialogue, it hints that the character wants a response; the ellipsis leaves the sentence incomplete.

Without the ellipsis, "Mister?" could be comprehended as someone simply wanting to grab the person's attention in a similar way to "Sir?".